# How do I classify an image into multiple classes?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, conv-neural-network

I wish to perform object detection on images. I am using Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) to perform object detection on images. My problem is, I want to draw bounding boxes for a cat in each image. In addition, I also wanted to give a tag 'white', 'black', 'other' to the detected boxes.

How do I add these tags to the detected objects?

Comment: I think more details are needed. Anyway, (by the theory) CNN will assign your object to only one of the classes. So you'll need to make classes like 'black cat', 'white cat', 'other cat' (which is not best solution), or make separate CNN/other method (eg. color averaging) to detect cat color, once CNN classifies your object as a 'cat' (regardless of the color). What tools do you use? Or You wrote CNN by yourself?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. I plan to use YOLO or else to write a CNN on my own